# Difference in Reference Frames between VLP 16 and HDL 32 and How to convert them?

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

How are the Reference Frames used in VLP 16 and HDL 32 differ from each other and How to convert them into a common frame of reference ?

I have point cloud data gathered from VLP 16 and HDL 32. May I know how their axes, X, Y, Z are oriented and how do these axes change between these two devices.

I would like to convert my HDL 32 data into the same frame of reference as that of VLP 16 so that both points returned by both geometrically and metrically mean the same, considering that their HDL 32 sits on top of VLP 16 at a height of 30 cm.

Thank you for your time!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260542/difference-in-reference-frames-between-vlp-16-and-hdl-32-and-how-to-convert-them--?/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2017-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/71
This has actually helped me.

VLP 16 axes of data published from ROS driver is different from the axes shown in VLP-16 manual.
In relation to a body the standard is:

x forward

y left

z up

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2017-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0